# How mock cheerio.load().toArray().slice();

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai, sinon, cheerio

Given below snippet

```
    static async parseData(): Promise<Foo[]> {
    const html: string = await this.fetchData();
    const $: cheerio.Root = cheerio.load(html);
    const elements = $('table#constituents tbody tr').toArray().slice(1);
    return elements.map(e => {
        const targetedHtml = $(e).html();
        if (targetedHtml){
            return Foo.createFromHtml(targetedHtml);
        }else{
            throw Error('invalid html');
        }
    });
}
```

How do you mock/stub line #4 to cover the throw case?
I basically want the slice to give me array of type `cheerio.Cheerio`
I feel like I know what to do but lack the syntactic knowledge to properly stub this.

Comment: I'd suggest you _don't_ - refactor this so there's a function that takes the HTML string and you can test that directly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for the suggestion but I'm trying to learn sinon stubbing/mocking. Are you suggesting against it because you'd have to stub `Array.prototype`?

Comment: You definitely don't mock the array interface - if you absolutely must use a test double, it should still return an array from toArray. And you can still mock the function that takes the string in the context of testing the overall parseData, if you really want to.